# What's the relationship between Pareto shape parameter (alpha) and exponential rate parameter (lambda)?

Tags: pareto-distribution, exponential-distribution

I'm trying to do my undergraduate research on non parametric density estimation for  a heavy tailed distribution. For that, I'm with a data set, which I assumed it should be Pareto distributed with the evidence of the histogram. But when I constructed the corresponding QQ plot, I couldn't see that it's Pareto any longer. Further more, I could find a parametric Pareto test, and by that, it significantly suggests that the data are not Pareto. It seems like exponentially distributed. Any how I'm supposed to do my research using the existing data set. So I again went back to my research topic, and tried to do required alterations, such as non parametric density estimation for "sales data", but not heavy tailed any longer. 
With this context, I'm interested to know the relationship between the shape parameter of the Pareto distribution, and, the rate parameter of the exponential distribution, so that I can think of somehow applying heavy tail to my research.

Comment: How did it go with this research?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some respects your question doesn't give enough information to make it possible to address all that you ask, but here I will address the question in your subject line:

> What's the relationship between Pareto shape parameter (alpha) and exponential rate parameter (lambda)?

The family of Pareto distributions is parametrized by a pair of positive numbers $(x_0,\alpha).$ If $X$ is a random variable with this distribution, then we have
$$
\Pr(X>x) = \left( \frac{x_0} x \right)^\alpha \quad \text{for } x\ge x_0.
$$
Let $Y= \log_e (X/x_0).$ Then for $y\ge0$ we have
$$
\Pr(Y>y) = \Pr\left( \log\frac X {x_0} > y \right) = \Pr(X> x_0 e^y) = e^{-\alpha y}.
$$
Thus $X$ has a Pareto distribution with parameters $x_0,\alpha$ precisely if $\log_e(X/x_0)$ has an exponential distribution with intensity $\alpha$ and expected value $1/\alpha.$

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful feedback. This is very simple to understand and clear.